# Get foreign key object in SearchQuerySet results Haystack

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I have the following models:

```
class EquipmentModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True)
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer, related_name="manufacturer")
    ....
```

and the following indexes:

```
class EquipmentModelIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    name = indexes.CharField(model_attr="name")
    manufacturer = indexes.CharField()

    def get_model(self):
        return EquipmentModel

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        return self.get_model().objects.all()
```

and that for my equipmentmodel_text.txt

{{ object.name }}
{{ object.manufacturer }}

However, whenever I perform this query:

```
    results = SearchQuerySet().models(EquipmentModel).filter(name__startswith=request.GET['q'])[:5]
```

I only get the manufacturer's pk. I want the whole object (or at least it's name). Is that possible?!

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To achieve that you must already [add the manufacturer's name](https://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/master/searchindex_api.html#prepare-foo-self-object) to the index when indexing:

```
class EquipmentModelIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    # your other fields
    manufacturer_name = indexes.CharField()

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        # using select_related here should avoid an extra query for getting
        # the manufacturer when indexing
        return self.get_model().objects.all().select_related('manufacturer')

    def prepare_manufacturer_name(self, obj):
        return obj.manufacturer.name
```

Comment: Okay it works! Now... I am bit confused as to what is the difference of the fields in EquipmentModelIndex and the ones in the equipmentmodel_text.txt...? In the .txt, should I put {{object.manufacturer.name}} or {{object.manufacturer_name}}? How come even if I remove complete manufacturer_name from the Indexes and the .txt, I can still access it from the objects returned from the SearchQuerySet?

Thanks!

Comment: With the txt you mean the template that is indexed? Of course you can put `{{ object.manufacturer.name }}` there as you work with Django's model objects there... You can still access the name if you remove it from the index because if you access `result.object` haystack loads the data additionally from the database... For good performance only work with data from the index (but then you need to keep it uptodate!).

Comment: This might be interesting for you: http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchqueryset_api.html#load-all,   https://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/master/best_practices.html#avoid-hitting-the-database

Comment: ok so that .txt tells Haystack which fields I allow my users to search in that specific model. Hence, I allow them to search for the manufacturer's name. Could I just put {{object.manufacturer}}? Also, theoretically, I don't need that manufacturer_name and prepare method if I just want to return the manufacturer's object when I load the EquipmentModel from Haystack?

Comment: `{{ object.manufacturer }}` will most likely output what the `__unicode__` method of the `Manufacturer` model defines... And you don't need the field in the index if it's ok for you to load it from the DB when displaying the results.